# Create pull request for docker dependency package if outdated

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, github

Platform: GitHub

CI/CD: GitHub Actions

Additional technologies: Docker with Ubuntu base image

I'm creating a Dockerfile and I need to install a package (such as Terraform). Every time the 'current_version' within "https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/terraform" changes, then I want a pull request made to the repo (to change a JSON file with version info).

I've also looked into options such as Dependabot and Renovate. Maybe create a Cron job?

I would appreciate some advice as to how to do this.

Here's how the code would look on a high-level:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get install # install packages such as curl and wget

wget -O terraform.zip https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${JSON_FILE.TF_VERSION}/terraform_${JSON_FILE.TF_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a docker file like this...

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG TF_VERSION=0.12.25

RUN apt-get install wget -y

RUN wget -O terraform.zip https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TF_VERSION}/terraform_${TF_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip
```

In your GitHub action you would need to get the current version from your Dockerfile.

```
export CURRENT_TF_VERSION=$(grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]*\.[[:digit:]]*\.[[:digit:]]*' Dockerfile)
```

Then the latest version of terraform.

```
export LATEST_TF_VERSION=$(curl -s 'https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/terraform' | jq -r .current_version)
```

Now in bash or using `if` and `outputs` in GitHub actions compare the two values. If they are not the same then find and replace the current version with the latest version in your Dockerfile.

```
sed -i "s/${CURRENT_TF_VERSION}/${LATEST_TF_VERSION}/" Dockerfile
```

Then you can use the [create-pull-request](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request) GitHub action to create a pull request.

The [create-pull-request](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request) documentation doesn't mention what happens if you don't have any changes but I asked [here](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request/issues/348). If it doesn't throw an error when you don't have changes then you could simply get the latest value and run sed.

```
sed "s/[[:digit:]]*\.[[:digit:]]*\.[[:digit:]]*/${LATEST_TF_VERSION}/" Dockerfile
```